# Simulate MQSeries server

Tags: ibm-mq

We have a legacy app using MQSeries C routine calls to send messages to an MQ Server. We don't have an MQ server in-house anymore, and we need to test a change that has been made to this legacy app before we release it to our client, who has their own (production) MQSeries server.

Is there a way we can simulate an MQSeries server which will emulate an MQSeries Queue Manager with channels and queues, and can receive messages sent to a particular queue. We don't need it to actually do anything with the messages, we just want it to 'look' like a standard MQSeries server, and communicate appropriately with the client.

If there is a way to do this in Java, that would be preferable, as that is the main source of knowledge in-house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know of anyway to simulate or emulate a IBM MQ queue manager, but you can do better and just download and install IBM MQ Advanced for Developers which is a full MQ queue manager installed that is licensed for no cost for development work.

The Tag Wiki for the [ibm-mq](/questions/tagged/ibm-mq) tag has a link to this download page along with many other useful links.

You can just click the tag and then click on "Learn More..." or click this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-mq/info) to go directory to the Tag Wiki.

Just install this and configure the needed channels and queues that you require.

Comment: As well as being able to install MQ Advanced for Developers yourself as Josh describes, you could pull down MQ in a Docker container (free developer edition) or use the managed MQ cloud service (free trial). These both stand up pre-configured queue managers that will accept client connections. If you need getting started information, try here https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/

Comment: @David Hmmmm, the cloud option looks like a good idea, but it's asking me to create an account with a credit card, so I'm not going to go there.

Comment: @JoshMC Any idea which of the 30 rpm's in the downloaded version 8.0.0 is the actual server for Linux?

Comment: Probably something like MQSeries-Server but it will have dependencies like Runtime.

Comment: Now that I'm at machine to look the name of the rpm would be `MQSeriesServer-x.x.s-x.x86_64` which requires `MQSeriesRuntime-x.x.x-x.x86_64` (fill in 'x` with the version number).

Comment: You should be installing MQ v9.0 or v9.1 unless you are specifically trying to match what your customer has.  That would also mean installing FixPack to bring it to the right level.  It is time to RTM.  Here is the starting point for MQ on Linux: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008640_.htm